# Linux C: Do System V message queues have a file descriptor on which `poll` can be called?

Tags: c, linux

The question is basically already in the title.

Do System V message queues have a file descriptor on which `poll` can be called such that the calling program knows as soon as possible in case a new message arrives?

Edit: Is it possible to link the file `pathname` returned by

```
key_t ftok (const char *pathname, int proj_id);
```

with the System V msg queue in case it uses the key `ftok` returns, like this?

```
int msgget (key_t key, int msg_flags);
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a `select/poll` equivalent. And, `ftok` is just a userspace way to [probably] get a _unique_ `key` value, based on dev/inode (?), but after that, they're not related. I've used SysV msgs quite a bit in commercial products. There may be a workaround, depending upon _how_ you intend to use the queues. But, SysV `msgrcv` will wake up instantly after another process/thread has done `msgsnd`. It is/was the only way to get the lowest latency of any other syscall like `futex` et. al.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you!